# Unable to run a Kentico Solution locally

Tags: iis, configuration, kentico

**The Situation**:
I am working on a website that has been recently updated from Kentico 8.2 to Kentico 9 and then from Kentico 9 to Kentico 10. According to the upgrade logs, all upgrades were successful, however, Kentico SmartSearch is no longer functional following the upgrades Error: "Error loading the WebPart 'SearchBox' of type 'SearchBox'".

**The Objective**:
My objective is to create a development copy of the live website in my local machine so I can fix the issue and test it locally and I am unsure on how to accomplish that.

**The Problem**:
I have asked for an exact clone of the folder, solution and Database from the live website, I've imported the database to my sql server and after that I've opened the solution on Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition, updated the CMSConnectionString to match the new db path and I've tried to build the solution, there were some errors that I've fixed by updating the references names, removing the obsolete ones and at this point the Solution Builds without errors, however I am unable to make it run on my local Machine, whenever I try to run it in my local machine I have the following exception:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
 current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
 about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set 
 to an instance of an object.

 Source Error: 

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current 
 web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception 
 can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

 Stack Trace: 


 [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
 object.]
 CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(String relativePath, 
 ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum, SiteNameOnDemand siteName, 
 ViewModeOnDemand viewMode) +2387
 CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(RequestStatusEnum status, 
 String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum) +61
 CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewritingHandlers.RewriteUrl(Object sender, 
 EventArgs e) +50
 CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler(EventHandler'1 h, TArgs e) +100
 CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise(String partName, List'1 list, TArgs e, 
 Boolean important) +714
 CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e) +100
 CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e) +143
 CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.StartEvent(TArgs e) +217
 CMS.Base.ApplicationModule.PostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs 
 e) +16
 System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep 
.Execute() +201
  System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& 
completedSynchronously) +73
```

**After checking IIS LOGS**:

I checked the the IIS event logs and when I try to run the website 2 events happen, I think this is due to some configuration error on my behalf but I cant quite figure out what is missing so here are the following items on the event viewer

1 - INFORMATION:

```
 Event code: 4005 
 Event message: Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid. 
 Event time: 6/8/2018 11:13:12 AM 
 Event time (UTC): 6/8/2018 10:13:12 AM 
 Event ID: 75f3f8236cca48e0b7d9156a7f648fc1 
 Event sequence: 2 
 Event occurrence: 1 
 Event detail code: 50201 

Application information: 
  Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Kentico10-1-131729263846745120 
  Trust level: Full 
  Application Virtual Path: /Kentico10 
  Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico10\CMS\ 
  Machine name: FAKENAME
Process information: 
  Process ID: 1392 
  Process name: w3wp.exe 
  Account name: FAKEDOMAIN\Jony.Bimbinz 

Request information: 
  Request URL: http://localhost/Kentico10 
  Request path: /Kentico10 
  User host address: ::1 
  User:  
  Is authenticated: False 
  Authentication Type:  
  Thread account name: FAKEDOMAIN\Jony.Bimbinz 

Name to authenticate:  

Custom event details:
```

2 - WARNING (Same as the original exception):

```
 Event code: 3005     
 Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.     
 Event time: 6/8/2018 11:54:58 AM     
 Event time (UTC): 6/8/2018 10:54:58 AM     
 Event ID: b16d590261134c3c9b988bdb01a24b73    
 Event sequence: 4     
 Event occurrence: 1     
 Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Kentico10-1-131729288917669454 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /Kentico10 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Kentico10\CMS\ 
    Machine name: FAKENAME 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 9336 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: FAKEDOMAIN\Jony.Bimbinz

Exception information: 
    Exception type: NullReferenceException 
    Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum, SiteNameOnDemand siteName, ViewModeOnDemand viewMode)
   at CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(RequestStatusEnum status, String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum)
   at CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewritingHandlers.RewriteUrl(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler[TArgs](EventHandler'1 h, TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise[TArgs](String partName, List'1 list, TArgs e, Boolean important)
   at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.StartEvent(TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.ApplicationModule.PostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



  Request information: 
    Request URL: http://localhost/Kentico10 
    Request path: /Kentico10 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: FAKEDOMAIN\Joao.Ferreira 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 10 
    Thread account name: FAKEDOMAIN\Jony.Bimbinz
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum, SiteNameOnDemand siteName, ViewModeOnDemand viewMode)
   at CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewriter.RewriteUrl(RequestStatusEnum status, String relativePath, ExcludedSystemEnum excludedEnum)
   at CMS.URLRewritingEngine.URLRewritingHandlers.RewriteUrl(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.CallEventHandler[TArgs](EventHandler'1 h, TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.AbstractHandler.Raise[TArgs](String partName, List'1 list, TArgs e, Boolean important)
   at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.RaiseExecute(TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.SimpleHandler'2.StartEvent(TArgs e)
   at CMS.Base.ApplicationModule.PostResolveRequestCache(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


Custom event details:
```

Comment: How are you setting up the site in IIS? A localhost site pointing to the /CMS folder? Do you have form authentication enabled in IIS for the Authentication setting? Any URL rewriting added in the web.config?

Comment: Hi @Rui , thank you for your reply, I've setup a localhost site pointing to the /CMS folder, Forms and Anonymous authentication are enabled in IIS and there are no URL rewriting rules added to the web.config.

Comment: can you create a static .ASPX page (e.g. test.aspx) in CMS folder and see if that can load up?

Comment: @Rui I am unable to load, I get "Invalid website" with the following message: Either the website is stopped or the requested domain name is not configured for any website: http://localhost/Kentico10/test.aspx
If you're an administrator of this site, you need to go to Sites and make sure the following domain name is configured either in the site properties or a domain alias of a running web site: localhost

Comment: do you have .net framework enabled for local IIS?

Comment: Hi again @Rui , Yes, .net framework is enabled for local IIS.

Comment: Hey @Rui do you have any more troubleshooting options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The main issue**
The main issue was due to the incorrect culture setting in the Sites application, the master page for the default culture was also missing so when the default path "/" was being hit the exception was thrown.

There was also an issue with the "Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid." exception and I was able to fix this by generating a new machineKey in IIS and edit the web.config file with it.

**The Solution:**
After some emails exchange with Kentico Support I was advised to scale back from SSL to get the site running on http:// (even if the CMS settings were forcing https) and so I did, I have edited the web.config file:

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

And have changed the IIS settings to allow http.

From that point I was able to finally login into the Administration page, which was no longer throwing the invalid website error, and I was able to:

- Change the domain to localhost in the Sites application.
- Change the default culture in the Sites application.
- Copied and published the master page into the correct culture.

And now the site is running as it should, I am still having some issues with some stylesheets but I believe these are unrelated to this question.

I would like to thank everyone who tried to help, specially to Kentico Support who were spot on!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't run the admin you may need to check that localhost is in your table CMS_LicenseKey if not, create a new record in the table that has the same data as production and and change licensedomain to localhost.  There could be another table involved but I am not sure?

Comment: thank you for your reply, There was in fact a localhost row in my CMS_LicenseKey table, I've replaced the LicenseKey to the one present in the production domain and changed the "DOMAIN:" portion to localhost but the issue remains, the exception seems to be always the same. I don't think there is any other table involved or at least related to it that I can see.